# How can I access unselectable text from windows?

Tags: windows-7, dwm

How can I access/copy unselectable text from windows (in Windows 7)?

For example, when a warning/error/info popup box (or window) appear, is there a way to access the text of it (when the text is unselectable)?

I'm wondering if there's a utility or method to possibly access such, sort of like a "DOM Inspector" for a web browser.

Note:

The text is in the form of a label, and not any sort of textbox or inputtable text element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a standard dialog box, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the title, contents, and the available buttons (OK, Cancel).

Comment: Mind = BLOWN. Where has this tip been all my life? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Password Viewer](http://www.itsamples.com/pub/PViewer.zip)

[image]

Drag and drop where you want it to reveal text.